# PHP boolean casting awkward

Tags: php, casting, boolean

I came to this issue at work and wondered why PHP behave like this:

```
$test = "insert";

$isInsert1 = $test == "update";             // false
$isInsert2 = (boolean) ($test == "update"); // false
$isInsert3 = (boolean) $test == "update";   // true
```

$isInsert3 should return false like the other two variables, shouldn't it? I think that for some reason, wich i don't know, php considers the $test variable before comparing it with "update" string.

I'd like someone to explain me that behavior.

Comment: In addition to the answers, have a look at the docs on [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the parentesis you are casting `$test` to boolean.

Strings always evaluate to boolean true unless they have a value that's considered "empty" by PHP (taken from the [documentation for `empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)):

1. `""` (an empty string)
2. `"0"` (0 as a string)

So in your case PHP are interpreting:

1. `$isInsert3 = (boolean) $test == "update";`
2. `$isInsert3 = ((boolean) $test) == "update";`
3. `$isInsert3 = true == "update";`
4. `$isInsert3 = true == true;`

Answer (score 5):

In the third line, `(boolean) $test == "update"` is interpreted as `((boolean) $test) == "update"`.
Then, PHP tries to evaluate `true == "update"` because a non-empty string is true, and then, the right hand side, `"update"` casts into true, so `true == true` is true.

Answer (score 2):

What PHP is "seeing" here:

first:

```
$isInsert1 = $test == "update";             // false

<=> $isInsert1 = ($test == "update"); 
<=> $isInerst1 = ("insert" == "update");
<=> $isInerst1 = (false) // -> false.
```

second:

```
$isInsert2 = (boolean) ($test == "update"); // false

<=> $isInerst2 = (boolean) ("insert" == "update");
<=> $isInerst2 = (boolean) (false);
<=> $isInsert2 = false; // false
```

third:

```
$isInsert3 = (boolean) $test == "update";   // true

<=> $isInsert3 = (((boolean) $test) == "update"); //$test "isset"
<=> $isInsert3 = (true == "update"); //"update" "isset"  ps.: true === "update" would be false!
<=> $isInsert3 = (true); // -> true
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

I think your main "Confusion" is the fact, that `true == "update"` equals `true`.
This is, because `==` in PHP means equal, but `===` means IDENTICAL!

See here for more information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

`bool == ANYTHING` will cause the right side to be casted to bool. And when casting to bool:

`(boolean)1 == (boolean)2 == (boolean)"AnyNotEmptyString" == true`

and

`false == (boolean)0 == (boolean)null == (boolean)""`. (and whatever I missed)

**Note**: NOT EVEN the String-represenation of a boolean will be casted to the boolean in question. When comparing a String with a boolean, all that matters is: *Is the string empty (or null, or "0")? then its FALSE!*:

```
(Boolean)"false" == false // -> will return false
(Boolean)"false" == true // -> will return true.
(Boolean)"true" == true // -> will return true.
(Boolean)"true" == false// -> will return false.
(Boolean)"0" == true // -> will return false.
(Boolean)"0" == false// -> will return true.
```

Snipped:

```
   <?php
echo ((Boolean)"false" == false)?"true":"false";
echo "<br />";
echo ((Boolean)"false" == true)?"true":"false";
echo "<br />";
echo ((Boolean)"true" == true)?"true":"false";
echo "<br />";
echo ((Boolean)"true" == false)?"true":"false";
echo "<br />";
echo ((Boolean)"0" == true)?"true":"false";
echo "<br />";
echo ((Boolean)"0" == false)?"true":"false";
?>
```

Comment: I think your explanation of how `$isInsert1` is set is incorrect.  `$isInsert1` is never set to a string - its value is the outcome of the expression `$test == "update"`, which is boolean.  It works the same way that the second example does, except without casting the boolean result to boolean.

Comment: @SurrealDreams You are right: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php `==` has a higher precedence thatn `=`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is connected with [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Actually (boolean) is operator with higher precedence than comparison. This means that the third line is equivalent of

```
$tmp = (boolean) $test; //true
$isInsert3 = (bool == "update"); // boolean true and non-empty string are treated as equal when you do ==
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this unexpected behavior is that in your third instance, you are casting `$test` to boolean, **not** the outcome of `$test == "update"`.

Casting "insert" to bool results in true - any non-empty string evaluates as true.  Then `true == "string"` evaluates to true, because the comparison of a boolean to other types treats both types as boolean.  Again, a non empty string like "string" is equivalent to true, so `true == true`, not surprisingly is equal to true.

Footnote - If you are comparing two variables with an operator like `==`, you don't need to cast the result to boolean.  The result will always be boolean.